# How to recover the login password for Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I have an old computer with Windows 10 installed and I gave it to my sister. I had two users setup on it, one is A, the other B.

I normally log in as A, and I chose to save an auto-login password for faster access.

Now when my sister got the computer she tried to login as B but didn't know the password, and I don't remember it either. Then she switch to user A but now she was prompted to enter a password, which she didn't know and I don't remember either.

Now the question is, how can I retrieve the password for either A or B so that we can log in w/o a problem.

Comment: local or 'cloud' accounts?

Comment: Is reseting the password good enough ?  (If it's unencrypted ofc)

Answer (score 2):

### ONE WAY:

1. Download this:

http://windowsmatters.com/tag/winpe/

It's Windows Live....

2. create bootable USB with:

https://rufus.akeo.ie

3. And use **Ntpwedit** tool

It's the easiest way IMHO

---

I personally use this particular live CD:

http://sergeistrelec.ru/winpe_10/64-winpe-10-sergei-strelec-x86-x64-20161006-english-version.html

But I know that russian software is red flag  for some people...

with **Active Password Changer** and **Reset Windows Password**

### ANOTHER WAY:

1. When booting, turn off your PC somewhere in the middle of booting process, repeat 1-3x
2. eventually you will get into recovery
3. Open CMD
4. Enter:

   ```
   move d:\windows\system32\utilman.exe d:\windows\system32\utilman.exe.bak
   copy d:\windows\system32\cmd.exe d:\windows\system32\utilman.exe
   ```
5. Boot you Windows normally, so you are on Login screen.
6. Click on utilman (ease of access ...whatever)
7. Enter:

   ```
   net user yourusername newpassword
   ```

### FOR LIVE ACCOUNTS

https://account.live.com/password/reset

[image]

Once you make it through these steps, you’ll be greeted with the generally familiar recovery process that most major companies will use when attempting to verify that you really are who you say you are. If you’ve registered an external email or a cellphone number with your account, you can receive a code which will pop your account open without any extra hassle.

[image]